# scheduled task"shutdown.exe" to reboot PC.where do I enter parameters?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I would like to create a scheduled task to reboot my XP PC.  I am trying to apply the instructions from the following link but http://www.winxptutor.com/schsd.htm , but I can not figure out where to apply the parameters. could it be that the field is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add the parameters in the same field as you specify the command. The task scheduler just takes the entire contents of the field.

So you'd have:

> shutdown.exe /parameter1 value1 ....